# Approximation of Poisson distribution problem

Tags: statistics

> Question: A certain type of particle is emitted at a rate of 900 per
>   hour. What is the probability that more than 950 particles will be
>   emitted in a given hour if the counts form a Poisson process?

I tried to solve this by myself and then I got stuck. I don't know how the book got its answer either :^( If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: It looks as if you've done about $99\%$ of the problem and everything you've done is correct. One caveat is that you shouldn't think this is accurate all the way out to that fifth digit (or even the third). $\qquad$

Comment: Ohhh!! I see, thank you so much for that tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind the solution given in the textbook is that when the rate parameter $\lambda$ is very large, then the Poisson distribution is approximately normal, with mean $\mu = \lambda$ and variance $\sigma^2 = \lambda$.  So, by standardizing the Poisson random variable $X$ that counts the random number of events per hour, and using an approximation, we get $$\Pr[X > 950] = \Pr\left[\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} > \frac{950 - 900}{\sqrt{900}} \right] \approx \Pr[Z > 5/3],$$ where $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$ is a standard normal random variable.  Then you simply look up the resulting probability in a normal distribution table:  if $\Phi(z) = \Pr[Z \le z]$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution, then the desired probability is simply $$\Pr[X > 950] \approx 1 - \Phi(5/3),$$ as the book claims.  Again, the takeaway here is that when $\lambda$ is big, $X$ is **approximately** normally distributed with mean and variance equal to the Poisson rate, therefore, $(X - \mu)/\sigma = (X - \lambda)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ is also approximately standard normally distributed.

If you want, you could also employ **continuity correction**, which would give you $$1 - \Phi(101/60) \approx 0.0461553,$$ instead of the book's answer.  This is because the Poisson count $X$ is a discrete variable, whereas the normal distribution is continuous; thus you need a correction factor to account for this.  But this is likely to be beyond the scope of your text.

If you have access to a computer algebra system, you can compute the **exact** probability using the Poisson distribution directly:  $$\Pr[X > 950] = \sum_{k=951}^\infty e^{-900} \frac{900^k}{k!} = 0.047119018020199065215 \ldots,$$ and you can see that this exact value falls between the approximations with and without continuity correction.  So here, we see that continuity correction doesn't give us much benefit.

---

To give you a sense of how well the approximation works, here is a rather crude animation which displays the PMF of a $\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ distribution (in blue) along with the PDF of a $\operatorname{Normal}(\mu = \lambda, \sigma^2 = \lambda)$ distribution (in orange), for increasing values of $\lambda$ from $1$ to $100$.  At the beginning, they are different; but as we increase $\lambda$, the approximation improves considerably.

[image]

It seems too good to be true.  The curves seem to match so well, right?  Actually, though, if we plot the function $$\rho(x) = \frac{\Pr[X = x]}{f_{Z \sqrt{\lambda} + \lambda}(x)},$$ that is to say, the ratio of the Poisson PMF to the density of its normal approximation, we find that even for $\lambda = 100$, we have the following picture:

[image]

This suggests that the Poisson distribution "tail" is quite a bit heavier than its normal approximation, and that the **relative** quality of the approximation is poor when we are looking more than about $4$ standard deviations away from the mean.

Comment: Holy moly thank you so much!! :''-) this is so detailed and helpful!